# Using sed and awk to edit lines in a file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a file of a few host names separated by spaces then a location.

```
host1 C1U5  
host2 C11U55  
host15 C5U10
```

I have to edit the file of hosts. I have written the sed/awk lines to remove characters but my sed lines just returns the full line. I need to remove the Cxx portion of the line.

```
awk '{print $2}' file | sed -e 's/([Cc][0-9].\\w+//g' | tee new new_file
```

The output should look like

```
host1 5  
host2 55  
host15 10
```

Comment: or I can use    sed -e 's/([U][0-9]\\w+//g'

Comment: can you paste what your output should look like? The question is not clear. Should the final output only have host1, host2... and so on ?

Comment: @MatiasBarrios I made the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will remove all except last numbers from your second field and you should get the desired output.

```
 awk '{ sub(/C[0-9]+\w/,"",$2); print $1,$2 }' f1
```

Output:

```
host1 5
host2 55
host15 10
```

Comment: Why gsub? You should go for sub in this situation.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs: Here it won't matter as there would be max one match per field. But yes considering performance sub is better as per benchmarks. I'll take it into account and will update too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**awk** solution:

```
$ awk '{sub(/C[0-9]+[^0-9]+/,"",$2)}1' file
host1 5
host2 55
host15 10
```

Explanation regex:

```
C              # C
[0-9]+         # followed by 1 or more digits
[^0-9]+        # followed by 1 or more non-digits
```

**sed** solution: you can use that very same regex

```
$ sed -E 's/C[0-9]+[^0-9]+//' file
```

Comment: @batMan Thx. Hope you agree on the gsub/sub remark.

Answer (score 1):

Sed solution :

```
ubuntu$ sed -E 's/.*(^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[ ])([C][0-9]*[U])([0-9]+).*/\1 \3/g' mytext.txt
host1  5
host2  55
host15  10
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Following awk may help you too on same.

```
awk -F'C[0-9]+\\w' '{print $1,$2}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
host1  5
host2  55
host15  10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{sub(/C.*U/,"")}1' file

host1 5  
host2 55  
host15 10
```

What happens?

sub removes all between both forward slashes.

From C and .=single character of any value

*= zero or more of preceding character to U.

,""= Here sub erases the content between forward slashes.

At the end 1 prints what is left.

Comment: This will remove `CPU` and even `CU`. `C` should be followed by a number. Apart from that, this solution looks awfully close to mine....